# How to configure Bind for Spamassassin

Tags: arch-linux, email, dhcp, bind, spamassasin

I'm wondering if anyone can help me out with following the directions I found here

https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/CachingNameserver

to set up a working configuration for Spamassassin. I think I have a problem which is, as it has been explained to me, that my ISP name servers are being blocked by the various DNSBL servers. So Spamassassin is not able to make DNSBL queries under my current system configuration, as DHCP has configured my `/etc/resolv.conf` to tell the DNS libraries to forward requests through my ISP's servers.

The above document describes a workaround, basically to have `named` route Spamassassin DNSBL queries directly to the DNSBL servers so that they come from my own IP, which presumably isn't blocked. At the same time, all other queries should go to the name servers configured by my local DHCP server, or something to that effect, for speed.

However, I found the documentation to be somewhat complex, for example it tells me to put something in `/etc/resolv.conf` but doesn't explain how I should make sure that my DHCP client doesn't overwrite that file. Also, it asks me to hard-code my ISP name servers in `/etc/named.conf` - but I'd rather have these configured by DHCP so that I don't have to worry about manually changing the configuration when I travel.

Can someone help me configure this? I would like to know what I should put in `/etc/named.conf`, and and any other configuration files, Systemd unit files, etc.

Also, the Spamassassin documentation doesn't explain what commands I can use to test that a query to one of the DNSBLs is failing in my current configuration, or how to verify that it succeeds in an improved configuration. It would be useful to know these things so that I can test that my setup is working.

If it matters, I run Arch Linux.

I apologize for being so inadequate at figuring these things out for myself. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which email server did you use? Did you have own DNS server?When you got webmail like squirrelmail.Actually you can configure spamassassin through squirrelmail for DNSBL.

Comment: I use a script to download mail from a server to my laptop. I run Spamassassin on my laptop. Are you going to say that I should just run it on the server? I suppose I could upload my local Bayes database to the server. The server doesn't move around, but it might still need to be configured to bypass the local nameserver for DNSBL queries. I hope I'm getting all this terminology right.

Comment: You need to configure djbdns and bind for domain blocker.When I read the documentation from the link.You just need to add ISP DNS as forwarder on named.conf.Djbdns will do domain blocker.Spamassassin was integrated with mail server like postfix.Spamassassin was not desktop application for anti spam.